# Triggering a Jenkins job from another Jenkins job, without remote URL Curl

Tags: jenkins

I'm working on building a Jenkins job that will trigger a pipeline to build a new AMI in one group, when a Golden AMI in another group becomes available. I need a way for a Jenkins job to initiate another Jenkins job without using the remote build URL method, because in the environment I'm working in it's not feasible to keep them all updated.

I've seen some things about plug-ins, but I'm a little fuzzy about which should be used here. Is there one that's recommended? Or is there a way to script this without the remote URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `build job` to start an existing pipeline in Jenkins.
It's part of the [Build Step](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-build-step/) plugin.

A simple example:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node { label 'nuc3' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Run External Jobs') {
            steps {
                build job: 'FOLDER_TEST_JOBS/test_job1_located_under_folder', wait: false
                sleep(60)
                build job: 'test_job_without_folder_path', wait: false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is super easy, just tried it out and it works fine. I wonder why so many other forum posts I found made this sound so complicated?

Thanks!